# Freemarker get-method without "get"

Tags: freemarker

How can I access method/field, using the following syntax:

`${object.foo}`
?
What i want is:
if there is a public field, named foo, then it's value returns,
else if there is a getter, named getFoo(), then it calls and result of call returns,
else if there is a method, named foo(), then it calls and result of call returns.
Is it possible in Freemarker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can write your own `ObjectWrapper` implementation it's possible, although if you need more than `object.foo` to work (like, exposing methods etc.) writing an object wrapper can be a *lot* of work. So, maybe a good compromise is using `DefaultObjectWrapper` or `BeansWrapper`. Where you configure FreeMarker:

```
BeansWrapper bw = new DefaultObjectWrapper() {

    @Override
    protected void finetuneMethodAppearance(
            Class clazz, Method m, MethodAppearanceDecision decision) {
        if (m.getDeclaringClass() != Object.class
                && m.getReturnType() != void.class
                && m.getParameterTypes().length == 0) {
            String mName = m.getName();
            if (!(mName.startsWith("get")
                    && (mName.length() == 3
                       || Character.isUpperCase(mName.charAt(3))))) {
                decision.setExposeMethodAs(null);
                try {
                    decision.setExposeAsProperty(new PropertyDescriptor(
                            mName, clazz, mName, null));
                } catch (IntrospectionException e) {  // Won't happen...
                    throw new RuntimeException(e); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

};
bw.setExposeFields(true);

cfg.setObjectWrapper(bw);
```

The priorities aren't exactly what you wanted though. `object.foo` will try things in this order: `getFoo()`, `foo()`, `foo`

Comment: I tried to do so and: freemarker.core.NonStringException: For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), but this evaluated to a sequence+method (wrapper: f.e.b.SimpleMethodModel) appears

Comment: That sounds like `decision.setExposeMethodAs(null)` wasn't called. Are you sure you install `bw` into the right `cfg` etc?

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. I changed m.getDeclaringClass() != Object.class to m instanceOf Object. That was a mistake. Your solution works perfectly, thx