# FreeMarker: how to get value of private attribute, not of public "get" method

Tags: field, private, freemarker

I am trying to get the value of **private** field (attribute) without using "get" method even when this method exists.

Is it possible?

I created several examples following [Freemarker get-method without "get"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918141/freemarker-get-method-without-get):

Example 1: Successfully use "get" method for "private" field

Class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String myField = "TestA";
    public String getMyField() { return "from method " + myField;   }
}
```

Template: Test:${myObject.myField}

BeansWrapper config:

```
bw.setExposeFields(true);
// bw.setExposureLevel(BeansWrapper.EXPOSE_NOTHING);
```

Output: "Test:from method TestA"

Example 2: Successfully get value of "public" field

Class:

```
public class MyClass {
    public String myField = "TestA";
    public String getMyField() { return "from method " + myField;   }
}
```

Template: Test:${myObject.myField}

BeansWrapper config:

```
bw.setExposeFields(true);
bw.setExposureLevel(BeansWrapper.EXPOSE_NOTHING);
```

Output: "Test:TestA"

Example 3: Can't get value of "private" field

Class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String myField = "TestA";
    public String getMyField() { return "from method " + myField;   }
}
```

Template: Test:${myObject.myField}

BeansWrapper config:

```
bw.setExposeFields(true);
bw.setExposureLevel(BeansWrapper.EXPOSE_NOTHING);
```

Output: Exception "The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> myClass.myField"

Answer (score 0):

None of the out-of-the-box `ObjectWrapper`-s (like `BeansWrapper`) allows reading `private` members. OTOH you can implement your own `ObjectWrapper` or extend an existing one (like `BeansWrapper`).